# Terraform template file loop over list

Tags: templates, ansible, terraform

Here is my code. It's supposed to generate an Ansible playbook file:

terraform.tfvars

```
cl_components = {
   cilium =  {
      enabled = "1",
      version = "1.13.4"
      repository = "https://helm.cilium.io"
   }
   traefik =  {
      enabled = "1",
      version = "24.0.0"
      repository = "https://traefik.github.io/charts"
   }
   cert-manger =  {
      enabled = "1",
      version = "1.14.1"
      repository = "https://charts.jetstack.io"
   }
}
```

main.tf

```
locals {

 component             = [
    for k,v in var.cl_components: k ]
  ver           = [
    for k,v in var.cl_components: v.version ]
  repo  = [
    for k,v in var.cl_components: v.repository ]
}

resource "local_file" "generate_playbook" {
  content =  templatefile("xox.tpl",
        {
        component  = local.component
        ver        = local.ver
        repo_url   = local.repo
        }
  )
  filename = "AAAA"
}
```

And here is the template file:

```
---
- block:
 %{ for name, ver in zipmap(component, ver)  ~}
  - name: ${name}
    helm:
      name: ${name}
      chart_ref: ${name}
      chart_version: ${ver}
      **chart_repo_url: ${nO idea how to add  the repo_url here...}**
%{ endfor ~}
```

++added
vars.tf

```
variable "cl_components" {
  type = map(any)
  description = "List of cluster components to be installed"
}
```

The above code is working almost 100% but I still can't figure out how to add  the 3rd variable **"repo_url"**

Comment: Have you tried using only `repo_url`?

Comment: Post variables.tf as well please?

Comment: If I add to the template file something like:   **chart_repo_url: ${repo_url}**

I get this error: : Invalid template interpolation value; Cannot include the given value
│ in a string template: string required

Comment: Remove the pipe (|) in chart_repo_url: $(repo_url) and try again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refactor your `templatefile` function arguments to use the entire variable as a parameter value:

```
content =  templatefile("xox.tpl", { components  = var.cl_components })
```

Note that your `locals` can now be discarded if they are unused otherwise. Now you can iterate through the variable value in your unrendered template and access the nested values accordingly:

```
---
- block:
%{ for component, attrs in components  ~}
  - name: ${component}
    kubernetes.core.helm:
      name: ${component}
      chart_ref: ${component}
      chart_version: ${attrs.version}
      chart_repo_url: ${attrs.repository}
%{ endfor ~}
```

Note additionally the `helm` module is updated to its FQCN `kubernetes.core.helm` as per Ansible best practices.

Answer (score 0):

...meantime I just figured out  a different approach...

main.tf

```
    resource "local_file" "generate_playbook" {
      content =  templatefile("xox.tpl",
            {
            _data = [for k,val in var.cl_components : {
               name       = k,
               isenabled  = val.enabled
               ver        = val.version
               ns         = val.namespace
               repo_url   = val.repository
            }]
            }
      )
      filename = "AAAA.yml"
    }
```

and template file::

[root@repovs01 XX]# cat xox.tpl

```
---
- block:
 %{ for n  in _data ~}
 %{ if n.isenabled == "1" }
  - name: Installing ${n.name}
    helm:
      name: ${n.name}
      chart_ref: ${n.name}
      chart_version: ${n.ver}
      chart_repo_url: ${n.repo_url}
      release_namespace: ${n.ns}
      create_namespace: true
%{ endif ~}
%{ endfor ~}
```